# gulp-iconfont generate wird font

Tags: sass, gulp

I have an issue with this gulp  task for font generation

```js
import path from 'path';
import gulp from 'gulp';
import iconfont from 'gulp-iconfont';
import iconfontCss from 'gulp-iconfont-css';
import config from './gulpfile.config';
import del from 'del';

//Compile svg files to icons font
gulp.task('iconfont', function(){
    gulp.src([`programs/${config.programs}/assets/svg-icons/ *.svg`])
        .pipe(iconfontCss({
            fontName: `${config.programs}`,
            path: 'node_modules/gulp-iconfont-css/templates/_icons.scss',
            targetPath: `../../../programs/${config.programs}/styles/base/_icons.scss`,
            fontPath: '../fonts/'
        }))
        .pipe(iconfont({
            fontName: `${config.programs}`, // required
            prependUnicode: false, // recommended option
            //prependUnicode: false,
            formats: ['ttf', 'eot', 'woff', 'woff2', 'svg'],
            // centerHorizontally: true,
            // normalize: true,
            // fontHeight: 1001,
            timestamp: Math.round(Date.now()/1000) // recommended to get consistent builds when watching files
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(`programs/${config.programs}/fonts`))
});
```

And it generate the fonts but when I use it in html

it show something like this in the screenshot bellow
[image]

How can I fix it to have the correct icon display instread?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue with TTF that rounds the coordinates of SVG icons, you have to set a higher font size see options: https://github.com/nfroidure/gulp-iconfont#options